# Drawing an image

Tags: android

I would like to know how to draw an image on android.
I'am currently doing it this way using Swift :

```
func rectangularCurvePath() { 
    var rectangleWithCurves: UIBezierPath!
    rectangleWithCurves = UIBezierPath()
    rectangleWithCurves.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 30))
    rectangleWithCurves.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30), radius: 30, startAngle: CGFloat(180.0).toRadians(), endAngle: CGFloat(270.0).toRadians(), clockwise: true)
    rectangleWithCurves.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width-30, y:0.0 ))
    rectangleWithCurves.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width-35, y: 35), radius: 35, startAngle: CGFloat(270.0).toRadians(), endAngle: CGFloat(0.0).toRadians(), clockwise: true)
    rectangleWithCurves.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y:30))
    rectangleWithCurves.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width-35, y: self.frame.size.height-35), radius: 35, startAngle: CGFloat(0.0).toRadians(), endAngle: CGFloat(100.0).toRadians(), clockwise: true)
    rectangleWithCurves.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: self.frame.size.height/1.2))
    rectangleWithCurves.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 30, y: (self.frame.size.height/1.2)-30), radius: 30, startAngle: CGFloat(135.0).toRadians(), endAngle: CGFloat(180.0).toRadians(), clockwise: true)
    rectangleWithCurves.close()

}
```

I am trying to do draw the following image.[image]

Comment: UIBezierPath is just a Path in Android.  Translating it should be trivial, the docs are here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

Comment: I tried the code which you have given reference link. But it does not work for me. Can you please give me some sample code